# Replace double quotes into single quotes?

Tags: javascript, typescript

It may sounds dumb but I don't succeed in replacing every double quotes of a string into simple quotes. Here is what I do:

```
const str = '1998: merger by absorption of Scac-Delmas-Vieljeux by Bolloré Technologies to become \"Bolloré\".';
console.log(str.replace(`"`, `'`));
```

And it ouputs :

```
1998: merger by absorption of Scac-Delmas-Vieljeux by Bolloré Technologies to become 'Bolloré"
```

What's going on here. I tried many other solutions... It just doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `str.replace()` only the first instance of a substring will be replaced.  You can use a regular expression and add the global flag to replace all instances.

> *str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)*
>
> **substr (pattern)** A String that is to be replaced by *newSubStr*. It is
>   treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular
>   expression. Only the first occurrence will be replaced.

```
console.log(str.replace(/\"/g, `'`));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace